# Cordova Android 10 - Trouble to assign the root path

Tags: android, cordova

As breautek wonderfully explain [here](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/issues/1354#issuecomment-921752541) , with Android 10 Platform (the mximum platform available at the moment on Cordova and the minimum platform required to publish on playstore) "XHR not CORS request" and "file://" not working if I don't set on my config.xml

```
<preference name="hostname" value="localhost" />
<preference name="AndroidInsecureFileModeEnabled" value="true" />
```

I'm pretty sure that this solution is useful... but temporary. I'm sure the PlayStore will impose a new restriction shortly and this solution will be in vain.

So I decided to not use them and carry on... I have solved my problem about XHR CORS request but I have no solution about how to set the root path... for example to assign it an image path

At the moment I get it as:

```
var urlRootMobile=cordova.file.applicationDirectory+'www/';
var img1 = urlRootMobile."/img/1.png";
var img2 = urlRootMobile."/img/2.png";
var img3 = urlRootMobile."/img/3.png";
```

Obviously don't work on my app because the path is : " file:///android_asset/www/img/1.png"

I tried to use "https://localhost/www"
I tried to use "https://localhost"
I tried to use "/"
But nothing...

I there some other command or trick ???

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [cordova-plugin-file](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file) to read these files.
If you just need to read images from www then the path is simply `'/img/1.png'`